I need an excel formula that if a number in cell A1 is 1,2 or 3 then put number 8 in cell A2. If not leave blank
I need an excel formula that if a number in cell A1 is 1,2 or 3 then put number 8 in cell A2.  If not leave blank.
I tried a bunch of formulas but I don't know what this one would be called. Sounds like a simple formula but I have alot to learn about Excel.

Try =IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1,{1;2;3},0)),"",8). In MS365 =IF(ISNA(XMATCH(A1,{1;2;3})),"",8) or =IF(ISNA(XMATCH(A1,SEQUENCE(3))),"",8).

I think ISNA(MATCH(A1,{1;2;3},0)) is the same as =NOT(OR(A1={1;2;3})

@rachel You're right, I'm needlessly taking out the big guns i.e. =IF(OR(A1={1;2;3}),8,"") works just fine.

=IF(OR(A1=1, A1=2, A1=3), 8, "")

This formula checks if the value in cell A1 is 1, 2, or 3. If it is, it places the number 8 in cell A2. If it's not, it leaves cell A2 blank.

Unfortunately none of these formulas worked

Try one of the following formula-
=IF((A1>=1)*(A1<=3),8,"")
=(A1>=1)*(A1<=3)*8



Since you mentioned that none of them worked, could you try this:
=IFERROR(IF(OR(0 + TRIM(A1) ={1,2,3}),8,""),"")


In case of these are numbers surrounded by spaces, TRIM to strip them
0 +  to convert to a number (-- is also used very often)
IFERROR is to handle error from the previous step
After getting a number, comparing it {1,2,3} results in TRUE/FALSE accordingly
In the example below, numbers are entered as text in D1-F1



Thanks for all the help!  It turns out it wasn't the formula that was the problem.  This formula worked-=IF(OR(A1=1, A1=2, A1=3), 8, "") Problem was that the cell was formatted for text instead of number!!
